# SQL - Create mapping table of unique values

Tags: sql, h2

I'm having some trouble figuring out the approach to the following:
I have a table containing vehicle information:

```
| id | vehicle_make | vehicle_colour | reg_number |
```

I have been tasked with creating a mapping table with the following structure:

```
| id | identifier | current | new |
```

The identifier can be either 1, 2 or 3 depending on if it's the make, colour or reg number we are mapping.  The current field should contain every possible unique value in vehicle_make, vehicle_colour and reg number.  The part I am struggling to figure out is that the new column must contain all of the unique values in current but swapped for another value with the same identifier to randomise the data.

For example in the mapping table you could have:

```
| id | identifier | current   | new     |
| 1  | 2          | 'red'     | 'blue   |
| 2  | 2          | 'blue'    | 'green' |
| 3  | 1          | 'vauxhall | 'audi   |
| 4  | 3          | 'W238K'   | 'Y659WE |
```

So in the new column you will always have another colour if there's a colour in the current column (identifier 2) and the same for vehicle make and reg number.

All values must be mapped to a different value, both columns current and new must contain unique values so for example red can't be mapped to both blue and green.

Comment: What DBMS? And must *every* attribute really be mapped to a *different* attribute? So with ten colors there must be not even a single color mapped to itself (which would be a typical result when we randomly assigned the colors anew)?

Comment: I'm using h2 and yes every attribute must be mapped to another, none can be mapped to itself and if there's an odd number assign new to an empty string.

Comment: An odd number would be no problem. E.g. A=B, B=C, C=A. No need for an empty string. My first idea was to randomly shuffle the colors, but then of course you could have a color in the same place. As this is forbidden, must this be random? Or could I simply match color1=color2, color2=color3, color3=color4, ... colorn=color1?

Comment: Oh yes that's true for the odd number.  This does need some element of randomisation as the point of this task is to anonymise / randomise the data so someone couldn't "easily" reverse engineer it.  Assigning colour1=colour2, colour2=colour3 wouldn't be enough

Comment: Okay. This is not so easy to do then with the two mentioned algorithms forbidden. Not a task for SQL in my opinion. Use a programming language instead to first retrieve the distinct colors, then shuffle them until no color matches itself, then fill your matches table. Same for makes and numbers of course.